# The harmonic number of any order is not an integer

Tags: number-theory, harmonic-numbers

In this site it has been proved that the harmonic number defined as:

$$\mathcal{H}_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$$

is not an integer. One proof I have seen uses Bertrand's postulate while others use elementary number thoery. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452794/harmonic-series-is-not-an-integer), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193781/alternative-proof-that-harmonic-sum-is-not-an-integer) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298475/can-any-partial-harmonic-sum-be-an-integer) and I guess elsewhere. Of course Bertrand's postulate is a killer for this question. Now, how would one prove that the harmonic number of any order , namely,

$$\mathcal{H}_n^{(k)}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^k}$$

is also not an integer ? I cannot think of something.

Comment: For powers $k\le -1$ these generalised harmonic numbers are certainly integers.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't clear. I meant the generalized harmonic number when $k\geq 1$. For $k=1$ I have many proofs, for $k\geq 2$ ?

Comment: If $k\ge2$, the sum is between $1$ and $2$, so not an integer.

Comment: I get that $\mathcal{H}_n^{(k)}\geq 1$ for $k\geq 2$. How do you prove the other inequality?

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: You can bound these sums by comparison with an integral.  That will suffice.  For instance, $\sum 1/n^2 < 1 + \int_{1}^{\infty} 1/x^2 \, dx = 2$.